# Chart Area Bring to Back not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Please can someone help me with my problem in SSRS wherein I need to "Bring to Back" the Chart series on my report so it will not overlap the vertical series bar graph. (please see below screenshot)[image]

I already tried to rearranged the the data but still in preview it overlap. (please see screenshot of my designer below)

[image]

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution to my problem. What I did is just, I used a "**Stack Area**" instead of "**Area**" only and then re-arranged the position of "**FTE**" and place it on top/first in the list.

[image]

and here is my order in the Chart Data in Designer mode:
[image]

Hope this will help others. Thanks :)